# Very long footnotes cause page breaks

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

If a document has *very* long footnotes close to each other in the main text, LaTeX start to compensate for this by breaking the page (see the first picture below).

I am grateful that TeX makes an effort to put footnotes close to the corresponding mark, but no thank you, TeX, this is too much. No matter what, it should **not** break the page, nor make the paragraph skips longer (which is almost as ugly) or use any of its other usual, dirty tricks; I prefer having the footnote five pages after the mark if that is what it takes. **Can someone find a way to make TeX stop breaking the page like this?**

I tried experimenting with both `bigfoot` and `interfootnotelinepenalty=0`, which changed the input, but did not remove the problem. Furthermore, `bigfoot` caused the nightmare shown on the second picture below. Notice that the footnotes run out of the page itself.

Note that `memoir` is not the problem either; change to article and load `geometry`, and exactly the same happens. Also, the A5 format is not the issue either; it just makes the problem even worse than when using A4.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{bigfoot}
%\interfootnotelinepenalty=0

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1-10]}
    \lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1-15]}
    \lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1-10]}
    This needs a footnote\footnote{\lipsum[1-10]}, and it is very necessary in order not to cause confusion.
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

The output **with `bigfoot`**:

[image]

Comment: i have doubts that what you ask is possible.  the behavior you see is what is described in the texbook.  maybe something could be done with luatex, but i suggest that you consider using endnotes instead.

Comment: Did Don really consider this strange behaviour of TeX to be *right*?

Comment: This isn't, of course, an answer to your question as stated, but have you considered turning your footnotes into endnotes? In `memoir`, the command `\foottopagenote` automatically re-purposes the `\footnote` infrastructure, and all you need to add is one or more strategically placed `\printpagenotes` commands. 12.6 in the latest `memoir` manual. Your readers may prefer "long" footnotes this way, too...

Comment: Probably: a footnote "five pages after the mark" is no longer, *stricto sensu*, a footnote....

Comment: If you look at books in the humanities which are "footnote-heavy", you'll see that they are quite commonly broken across pages. Presumably because it is necessary to do this to avoid absurd amounts of whitespace (but I've never asked).

Comment: I would like to stick to footnotes rather than endnotes, if necessary; my document is several hundred pages long with *many* footnotes, and I would like not to have to go to the back every thirty seconds.

Comment: @jon, well I would love to have my footnotes broken, if that solved my problem. In fact, I think I would prefer breaking them, because this causes a more even distribution of the text across the pages. But `interfootnotelinepenalty=0` (or even negative values) did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Gaussler -- i believe that don never considered that two very long footnotes, each requiring more than a page, would ever possibly be triggered on the same line.  certainly, i have never seen evidence that he himself would do such a thing.  and i don't think he would consider such a footnote style to be a service to his readers.  consider the quote in one of his epigraphs: "don, don't use footnotes." (jill knuth)  (from memory; not within access range of a texbook.)

Comment: Also: `\usepackage{bigfoot}` *and* `\DeclareNewFootnote{default}` is how to use `bigfoot` with regular footnotes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, in fact I am using LuaTeX for this document, so I would only love having a LuaTeX solution.

Comment: You should try with `\lipsum*` everywhere, because `\lipsum` adds paragraph breaks that make it more difficult to see the real result. With this I get no strange break, with pdflatex or lualatex

Comment: Strange, it still happens in my "real" document. Could be because I'm putting the footnote mark on the *left* of the text instead of one the *right*.

Comment: @Gaussler Anyway, I can't get the output like yours, even with the same example.

Comment: That is strange indeed; sure you're looking on page 9--10?

Comment: I'm using TeX Live 2014 BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to change `\floatingpenalty` in `\@footnotetext` (globally or locally). But imho it would much saner to shorten the footnotes.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty 100 %<---
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}
```

### Edit 2017

As packages like footmisc can change `\@footnotetext` it is probably better to patch the definition (after all packages which could change the definition again have been loaded):

```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\@footnotetext{\@MM}{100}{}{\fail}
  \makeatother
```

Instead of a fix value of `100` one could also use a command or a counter which could be redefined locally.

Comment: I assume you also want a `\makeatother`?

Comment: And I still get the same, unfortunately.

Comment: the `\makeatletter` is necessary, the `\makeatother` not ;-)

Comment: Well it works for me with your example.

Comment: It worked in my MWE, but not in my original document. How strange.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I’ve noted that the LaTeX kernel sets `\dimen\footins` to `8in` (see `latex.ltx`, l. 6219), and that this value seems to remain in effect when the document is typeset.  This could explain why, with A5 paper, setting `\floatingpenalty` to a small value does not yield the desired result in all situations (if TeX is allowed to fill up a whole page with footnotes, it might prefer to do so even if floating a footnote to a later page isn’t much costly…).