# Is there a way to allow footnotes to be displayed on a different (say, adjacent) page from the one where the marker appears?

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking

I would like to know if there's an "automated" (non manual) way to allow footnotes to be displayed on a different (say, adjacent) page from the one where the marker appears.

I ask this because I am writing a thesis with a lot of footnotes and some of them are very long and related to words close on the main text so that, being unable to put both footnotes on the correct pages, the compiler just send the main text (where the footnotes appear on close words) to another page, leaving a lot of blank space on the previous page; I would just prefer if the main text and the footnote marker could be kept on the "first" page and the relative footnote text be displayed at the bottom of the next page.

I'm using *report* document class

> \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

and the only package footnotes-related I added is *footmisc*

> \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

Also, the following commands are included in the preamble (I don't know if this is relevant)

> %Set space between footnotes and main text
>
> \setlength{\skip\footins}{0.7cm}
>
> %Set space between footnotes
>
> \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm}

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This depends on some details of your set-up.  Please post code showing your document class and the footnote relevant packages that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @AndrewSwann! I'm using _report_ document class:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report} and the only package footnotes-related I added is this: \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

Comment: Lucia, thank you. It is best to edit your question to include this extra information.  Even better is if you can make a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the problem.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238415/2388 (depending on your footmisc use, you will need a slightly different definition)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much! It looks like that's the exact same issue!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A silly question: how should I proceed to modify \floatingpenalty in \@footnotetext ? I mean, where should I find \@footnotetext ?

Comment: I added an edit to my old answer which shows how you can patch the command. Imho this should work more or less always. Instead of "100" you could also use a command like "\myfloatingpenally" that you can change locally to other values. (Don't forget to define the command ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for real! I use _texpad_ for Mac and it gives me the following error: "xpatch.sty not found". I guess this editor is unable to load packages on the fly and I usually add them manually...
But I'm unable to find the sty of the xpatch package: where should I look for?

Comment: TeXLive systems (as you probably have) don't have an on-the-fly installation method. But can't you use the package manager of your texsystem or on a terminal `tlmgr install xpatch` ?

Comment: Oh I just realized that I typed xpatch, when etoolbox should be enough.

Comment: I managed to install xpatch from Terminal; it looks like this code fixes most of the issues in the text, thank you!
Nonetheless, it gives me the error "Undefined control sequence \makeatatother"!

Comment: Yes sorry, the \makeatatother was a "stutter", I corrected it. If it solved your problem I suggest to close this one as duplicate and you can upvote the other if you want.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Correct me if I'm wrong: in the preamble, I should first insert the code of your "2017 Edit" (after all packages as been loaded) and then insert the big piece of code originally featured in your reply...right? And, eventually, after this add the ones already there to set the space between footnotes and main text and footnotes?
The fact is that, doing so, the line spacing between footnotes is altered (it becomes the same of main text) and I can't figure out why!
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: No, you should only add the 4 lines "Edit code".

Comment: Oh ok! I added that 4 lines right after loading all the other packages but it looks like it doesn't do trick! (there is no more the problem of the line spacing but the footnotes don't go to the adjacent page)

Comment: Maybe it's because there are those other lines in the preamble? (the lines in the OP)